# Use output of one stack as environment variable for lambda in other stack with SAM or Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I want to use the exported output of one cloudformation stack as environment variable for a lambda in an other stack.

Scenario:

- Stack1: QueueStack - Contains an sqs queue 'myQueue'. The stack exports the output of the queueUrl: `"${AWS::StackName}-myQueueUrl"`
- Stack2: LambdaStack - Contains the lambda function that will put something on this queue. The lambda function has an env. variable 'QUEUE_URL' that should contain the url of the queue. I want to dynamically use the Url outputted by the QueueStack. Something in the likes of:

```
   Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
   Properties: 
     Environment:
         Variables:
             QUEUE_URL: 
             - Fn::ImportValue:
                 Fn::Sub: "${QueueStackParameter}-myQueueUrl"
```

However this is not possible since environments variables can only be strings.

How can I use the exported output of one cloudformation stack as environment variable for a lambda in an other stack without cloudformation complaining that env vars have to be a string?

**UPDATE**

When writing it like this, it does work:

```
  QUEUE_URL: !Join
  - ''
  - - "Fn::ImportValue":
        "Fn::Sub": "${QueueStackParameter}-myQueueUrl"
```

However when using the normal `ImportValue` syntax, it does not work:

```
  QUEUE_URL:
    - Fn::ImportValue:
        Fn::Sub: "${QueueStackParameter}-myQueueUrl"
```

CloudFormation then returns the following status reason:
`Value of property Variables must be an object with String (or simple type) properties`

Comment: We use `Fn::ImportValue` in `Environment` variables a lot - in lambda functions, ECS Task definitions etc. So it is known work.
Maybe there's some more primitive mistake like mismatch of output name vs. what you specify in `ImportValue`?

Comment: @lexicore , I updated my question. It works when I first use a workaround to have it as a `string`. But it does not work when using the normal `ImportValue` syntax. I updated the question with examples.

Comment: Turned out to be a syntactical error. I should not use the 'dash' in front. It's not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an array, so there shouldn't be a dash in front.
It will work when you write it like this:

```
   Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
   Properties: 
     Environment:
         Variables:
             QUEUE_URL: 
               Fn::ImportValue:
                 Fn::Sub: "${QueueStackParameter}-myQueueUrl"
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative idea is use AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store to share data between the 2 stacks. In `QueueStack`, add an `AWS::SSM::Parameter` named with a predictable path e.g. `/QueueStack/URL`:

```
Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
Properties: 
  Type: String
  Name: /QueueStack/URL
  Value:
    Ref: "MyQueue"
```

Then, in your `LambdaStack` the `QUEUE_URL`, you can do this to reference it:

```
   Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
   Properties: 
     Environment:
         Variables:
             QUEUE_URL: '{{resolve:ssm:/QueueStack/URL:1}}'
```

Here is a reference link on this topic https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html

Comment: The value of the `AWS::SSM::Parameter` in the `QueueStack` then would be something like `!Ref MyQueue` ?

Comment: That is correct. According to the docs for `AWS::SSM::Parameter`, the default attribute `Ref` gives you the URL. I expanded my answer with a code snippet showing my work.